# How can I get notified in my website if user log out from facebook in other tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have integrated facebook login in my website using javascript SDK.
Now, if user logged out in other tab, how would my website come to know about it?
Please help.

Comment: Using cookies... Set some cookie as expired when user logged out!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Here are a few:

> 1. Checking via the JavaScript SDK if the user is still logged in
> 2. Cookies / Local Storage
> 3. Catching errors everytime the JavaScript SDK is called by not assuming that the user is still logged in or with the right permissions

Comment: I am already checking via javascript SDK. For that I am using **FB.getLoginStatus** api call. But it always returns me cache resposne. So even if I logged out from some another tab, on my website it still shows me that user is logged in.

Comment: You can also update the cookies after FB.logout completes. **FB.logout(function(response){ /* Update cookies here */ })**